# Flutter FirebaseAuth Handle Login/Register Exceptions

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a login/register form using FirebaseAuth.
However, whenever I try to login/register, I can't seem to catch the exceptions when the details are wrong even though everything is inside a try/catch.

Here's my code:

```html
    // my authentication is done with a Bloc, this is the event that's invoked when pressing the login btn
    Future<void> _onSignIn(
        AuthEventSignIn event,
        Emitter<AuthState> emit,
      ) async {
        try {
          emit(
            state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.loading),
          );

          final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
          final email = event.email;
          final password = event.password;
          
          // sign in and get user credentials
          // crashes when empty/wrong details are passed... aren't exceptions supposed to handle that?
          final userCredentials = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email,
            password: password,
          );
      
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        // my app crashes here instead of catching exception!
          print(e.code);
          emit(
            state.copyWith(
              status: AuthStatus.error,
              authError: e.code.toAuthError(),
            ),
          );
        } catch (e) {
            // or here
          print(e);
        }
      }
    )
```

It's as if my app isn't receiving any calls back from firebase (It's linked to my Firebase Project, as I can create & login into existing accounts, but not a single exception is ever caught!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64604045/i-cant-catch-the-exception-of-firebase-auth-on-flutter) by @CrimsonFoot

It turns out, my IDE stopped on EVERY exception, instead of only on 'Uncaught exceptions':

[image]

The solution was to tick 'All Exceptions' off